# redis slave node continually require auth

Tags: redis

I have deployed a redis service using master-slave mode with 3 nodes at Kubernetes. And I using sentinel to keep it stay high avaliable. All node has set `requirepass` and `masterauth`.

When I connect to any of slave node, execute auth command, and after few seconds no op, about 5-15 seconds, redis require auth again.

As I know, redis has no auth expired settings item. So I'm curious is this a redis mechanism which I don't know or there is problem at my redis service.

Comment: sharing the authentication  code - can assist in giving you an answer

Comment: authentication code: region-agent-a1

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your Redis server has set `timeout` config as N seconds.

The `timeout` option controls whether or not to *close the connection after a client is idle for N seconds (0 to disable)* (quote from redis.conf).

You connect to Redis with redis-cli, and send `AUTH` command to Redis. However, if you do not send any other commands in N seconds, Redis will close your connection. Then you send a new connection with redis-cli, redis-cli will create a new connection and send the command. However, since this is a new connection, and no `AUTH` command has been sent on this connection, you will fail and Redis asks you for authentication.

Comment: I have not set the timeout option. It remains the default value 0 which is disable. And only connect to slave node have this situation. master node is totally normal